# How to search for a specific link in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I'm trying to find out what would be the easiest way to search for a specific link in a site collection. It isn't a SharePoint link but a link to an external site. I tried to configure a custom search page but it doesn't seem to pick up navigation links.

I want to be able to find everything that contains that URL - whether it's a document, a navigation link, a link s list or a link existing as a text on a page or in a content editor. Is this possible out of the box?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if the link is in a document or on a page, as the link will be treated as text strings while searching.

But it is not possible for site navigations since they are not included in search crawls.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-sure-content-can-be-found