# SharePoint Online Search by URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I recently migrated my company Intranet from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online.
I want to make sure that we do not have any lingering links with URLs pointing to the old domain.

How do I search for just a specific URL like: http://oldintranetdomain* to locate any links to the old site?

This should be easy, but today I'm having a meltdown and being a bit thick.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, content is automatically crawled based on a defined crawl schedule. It is possible if the link is in a document or on a page, as the link will be treated as text strings while searching.

Reference:
[Make sure content can be found](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-sure-content-can-be-found)

A similar post:
[How to search for a specific link in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286042/how-to-search-for-a-specific-link-in-sharepoint-online)